# Simultaneous transactions in Firebase Realtime Database are failing to get most recent data (Swift)

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to make multiple updates to my firebase realtime database at the same time using transactions, but when I do this the calls aren't waiting for one another, and instead I only get one update instead of the seven I should be getting.

Below is a segment of my code that is called 7 times in a for loop:

```
global.newGame.runTransactionBlock({ (currentData: MutableData) -> TransactionResult in
        if let post = currentData.value as? NSDictionary {
            let player0Info = post["player0Info"] as? NSDictionary
            var serverHand = player0Info!["Hand"] as? Array<Int>
            serverHand?.append(2)
            print("The value of serverHand is \(serverHand ?? [-1])")
            global.newGame.child("player0Info/Hand").setValue(serverHand)
        }
      return TransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)
    }) { (error, committed, snapshot) in
      if let error = error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
      }
    }
```

And the output it gives is

```
The value of serverHand is [2]
The value of serverHand is [2]
The value of serverHand is [2]
The value of serverHand is [2]
The value of serverHand is [2]
The value of serverHand is [2]
```

Is there a way to prevent this from happening? Why doesn't putting this inside of a transaction keep it from being simultaneously changed by multiple calls?

As a side note, everything works as expected when I make these calls in spread-out intervals, I only get this issue from overlapping transactions.

Comment: Are you saying you're running that code *seven different times* within a for loop; which means it's seven *different transactions* which could return results in any order since firebase is asynchronous? The only guarantee a single transaction offers is that either all of the code *within that transaction* either passes or fails. So it's not really clear what you're asking or what the expected result is. Oh, and as a guess, `serverHand` is 2 because this `player0Info!["Hand"] as? Array<Int>` is an empty array so you're appending 2 to it every time (which results in printing '2' seven times)

Comment: Oh, also, the currentData is the well, currentData and that needs to be updated and returned in this call `return TransactionResult` but I don't see that being updated so the currentData will just return the data it contained in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an iOS dev, so expect typos/syntax errors.

From what I can tell, the way you handle the transaction is incorrect. When using a transaction, you ask for the "latest" data (see note), mutate that data, then send it back. However, in your code you are getting the data, mutating it and then at the same time, both overriding it using `setValue` and sending the changed data back. Because you are using `setValue` here, you create a loose infinite loop - where sometimes the transaction finishes first (everything is okay) and sometimes the `setValue` finishes first (the transaction is tried again).

A transaction is not a one-time operation, if the data at the location you are using is modified, the transaction can be retried. In this case, the call to `setValue` can trigger one of these retries.

If `serverHand.append()` mutates the array (i.e. you don't need to also add `player0Info!["Hand"] = serverHand.append()`), then simply removing the `setValue` should fix your problem.

Lastly, as pointed out by [@Jay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2851937) in this answer's comments, you need to also set `currentData.value` with the new data to commit any changes.

```swift
global.newGame.runTransactionBlock({ (currentData: MutableData) -> TransactionResult in
  if let post = currentData.value as? NSDictionary {
      let player0Info = post["player0Info"] as? NSDictionary
      var serverHand = player0Info!["Hand"] as? Array<Int>
      serverHand?.append(2)
      print("The value of serverHand is \(serverHand ?? [-1])")
      // note that the setValue was removed
      currentData.value = post; // link new data for updating
  }
  return TransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)
}) { (error, committed, snapshot) in
  if let error = error {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
  }
}
```

**Note:** I used "latest" in quotes because the first time a transaction is tried, the locally cached data is used to process the transaction. If the server's data is different from what's cached locally, the transaction will be processed a second time.

**Edit 1:** Added [@Jay's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2851937) contributions and removed brief references to the log messages being abnormal, as if called in a loop, multiple logs are to be expected.

Comment: Great effort here but I believe the issue (there are a number of issues) with the OP's code is that they are not updating the `currentData` and returning that with the .success call. Therefore, nothing is updated. e.g. the currentData *returned* is the currentData that was *passed in* with no changes. Oh, the repeated log message is due to the entire function *that is called 7 times in a for loop:*

Comment: Thank you! I took out setValue and replaced it with currentData.value = (updated value of post) and everything is working as expected.

Comment: @Jay I seem to have wrongly believed that `currentData.value` got the value by reference, rather than made a copy. If it did get the value by reference, mutating the child properties would be reflected on the original `currentData.value` property. And yes, I obliviously missed that "throwaway line" about the for loop. Time for coffee.

Comment: @RhettCarsonOwen While the explanation text is spot on, the code is not correct (as mentioned above). The `currentData` that's passed into the transaction is never mutated. e.g. `post = currentData.value` and so `post` contains the data but it's never changed in the transaction so what's passed back to write to Firebase is exactly the same data that was passed in. The `post` needs to be modified if you want it to contain new data. The solution is to append `2` to the `serverHand` array in the `post` object. I would like to mention that arrays should be avoided in NoSQL databases (Firebase)